# AngularJS: Rotate Image after Camera Capture

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am taking a picture with my android phone using AngularJS technology on ionic framework. This is my code review in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>

</ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my code in app.js

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }
});
```

My challenge is to rotate the image. If it were Java android I could easily rotate the image using Exif orientation but in this case I dont know how to go about it performing the rotation 90 degrees with angularjs. Please help me out. This is my first time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by adding this to app.js controller camera option

using the orientation option.

And it worked like charm.

Comment: Hey, can you provide code sample? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
correctOrientation: true
```

targetWidth small then 700

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas rotation as shown like here http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html

It would be something like this:

```js
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            var img = angular.element('img'),
                canvas = angular.element('canvas'),
                context,
                ch,
                cw,
                cx = 0, 
                cy = 0;

            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            cw = img.width;
            ch = img.height;
            canvas.width = cw;
            canvas.height = ch;

            // draw image to canvas
            context.drawImage(img, cx, cy);

            // calculate coordinates for image
            cw = img.height;
            ch = img.width;
            cy = img.height * (-1);

            // rotate 90 degrees
            canvas.setAttribute('width', cw);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', ch);
            context.rotate(degree * Math.PI / 180);
            context.drawImage(img, cx, cy);

        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah. Is a nice one but the dude is using jQuery but I need angularjs technology solution. Best of regards. My present challenge now is to select from gallery dont know if you can be of help to that.

Comment: Well, there was no jQuery at all. I didn't understand you've got an issue in camera image orientation.
As for files upload, try to use https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: On click of the Take Picture Button, nothing happens. Using the above solution

Comment: Didn't test it. Maybe issue is in image height and with. Will try to debug. The main point is to draw image to canvas and then rotate that canvas.

Comment: On the browse from Gallery I need a solution that will enable me re-use my already existing img src.